# Patterns in flex

Tags: flex-lexer

I want to write a rule in flex that is equivalent with:
symbol = lowercase|digit|other.
I defined these rules:

```
SYMBOL {LOWERCASE}|{DIGIT}|{OTHER}
ALPHABET SYMBOL+
LOWERCASE [a-z]
DIGIT [0-9]
OTHER [!#$%-./:;<>=?@\[\]^'~]
%%

  /* SYMBOL */
SYMBOL  {
        printf("Symbol found: %s",yytext);
        }
```

%%

If the input is "something123." it is not parsed.
SYMBOL is not recognized even if I define it after OTHER.

If I change the code like that:

```
SYMBOL {LOWERCASE}|{DIGIT}|{OTHER}
ALPHABET SYMBOL+
LOWERCASE [a-z]
DIGIT [0-9]
OTHER [!#$%-./:;<>=?@\[\]^'~]
%%

  /* SYMBOL */
{LOWERCASE}|{DIGIT}|{OTHER}  {
                             printf("Symbol found: %s",yytext);
                             }
%%
```

it works.
Shouldn't SYMBOL be replaced with {LOWERCASE}|{DIGIT}|{OTHER} ? [something like define from C]

LE:
Problem solved:
between %% some rules %% flex is searching for the exact matching. So it searches for SYMBOL like a simple word not for the pattern SYMBOL. The solution (specify the patterns): replace SYMBOL with {SYMBOL}.
So now it works:

```
SYMBOL {LOWERCASE}|{DIGIT}|{OTHER}
ALPHABET SYMBOL+
LOWERCASE [a-z]
DIGIT [0-9]
OTHER [!#$%-./:;<>=?@\[\]^'~]
%%

  /* SYMBOL */
{SYMBOL}  {
        printf("Symbol found: %s",yytext);
        }
```

Comment: You can post the solution you've found and mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

(Answered as a community Wiki by copying and pasting to close the question: [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

LE: Problem solved: between %% some rules %% flex is searching for the exact matching. So it searches for SYMBOL like a simple word not for the pattern SYMBOL. The solution (specify the patterns): replace SYMBOL with {SYMBOL}. So now it works:

```
SYMBOL {LOWERCASE}|{DIGIT}|{OTHER}
ALPHABET SYMBOL+
LOWERCASE [a-z]
DIGIT [0-9]
OTHER [!#$%-./:;<>=?@\[\]^'~]
%%

  /* SYMBOL */
{SYMBOL}  {
        printf("Symbol found: %s",yytext);
        }
```